# Inequality in proof of Huisken's theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Suppose $M$ is a uniformly convex hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ ($A\geq \alpha Hg$ for $\alpha>0$) undergoing mean curvature flow. $A$ denotes the second fundamental form and $H$ denotes the mean curvature.

The proof of Huisken's theorem uses a uniform bound on the following quantity.
$$
  f_{\sigma,\epsilon} = \left(|A - \frac1nHg|^2-\epsilon H^2\right)H^{2-\sigma}
$$
for some $\sigma\in (0,1)$ and all $\epsilon>0$. This is done by computing the evolution of $f_{\sigma, \epsilon}$, estimating some of the terms, and then using the maximum principle.

I am confused about the following inequality in p.294 of *Extrinsic Geometric Flows* by Andrews et. al:
$$
\gamma \frac{|\nabla A|^2}{H^2}H^\sigma\geq \gamma f_{\sigma,\epsilon}\frac{|\nabla A|^2}{H^2} \tag{1}
$$
This implies that $H^\sigma\geq f_{\sigma,\epsilon}$ since $\gamma>0$ and $H>0$. However, using $|A|^2\leq H^2$, the best inequality I can get is
\begin{align*}
\frac{f_{\sigma,\epsilon}}{H^\sigma} = \frac{|A|^2}{H^2}+1-\frac{2}{n}-\epsilon\leq 2-\frac{2}{n}-\epsilon\,.
\end{align*}
In fact, using uniform convexity $A\geq \alpha Hg$, we have
$$
\frac{f_{\sigma,\epsilon}}{H^\sigma} =\frac{|A|^2}{H^2}+1-\frac{2}{n}-\epsilon\geq \alpha + 1-\frac{2}{n}-\epsilon
$$
so for large $\alpha$ we would have $f_{\sigma,\epsilon}\geq H^\sigma$. What am I missing here?

I have added an excerpt from the book below.

**Context**: one of the terms in the evolution equation for $f_{\sigma, \epsilon}$ is $$-2H^\sigma|\nabla\frac{A}{H}|^2$$ Then, in p.294 they show that if $A\geq \alpha Hg$ for $\alpha>0$, then
$$
|\nabla\frac{A}{H}|^2\geq \gamma\frac{|\nabla A|^2}{H^2}
$$
where $\gamma$ depends on $\alpha$ and $n$. Since $A\geq \alpha Hg$ is preserved under mean curvature flow, the above inequality holds for as long as the flow exists with the same constant $\gamma$. This leads to the left side of (1).

**Edit:** Huisken's original argument (Section 5 of [this](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-20/issue-1/Flow-by-mean-curvature-of-convex-surfaces-into-spheres/10.4310/jdg/1214438998.full)) makes sense to me. He considers the slightly different function
$$
  f_\sigma = (|A|^2 - H^2/n)H^{2-\sigma}\,.
$$
Computing the evolution of $f_\sigma$, we have
\begin{align}
  (\partial_t-\Delta) f_\sigma &= \frac{2(1-\sigma)}{H}\langle\nabla H,\nabla f_\sigma\rangle\\
  &-\frac{2}{H^{4-\sigma}}|H\nabla A - A\otimes\nabla H|^2\\
  &-\frac{\sigma(1-\sigma)}{H^{4-\sigma}}(|A|^2-H^2/n)|\nabla H|^2\\
  &+\sigma|A|^2f_\sigma\,.
\end{align}
Using an earlier inequality (Lemma 2.3(ii)) and preservation of $A\geq \alpha Hg$, the following is true under the flow
$$
  |H\nabla A - A\otimes\nabla H|^2 \geq \frac12 \alpha^2 H^2|\nabla H|^2
$$
So the last three terms of $(\partial_t-\Delta) f_\sigma$ are bounded above By

\begin{align}
&-\frac{\alpha^2 H^2}{H^{4-\sigma}}-\frac{\sigma(1-\sigma)}{H^{4-\sigma}}(|A|^2-H^2/n)|\nabla H|^2+\sigma|A|^2f_\sigma \\
&=-\frac{|\nabla H|^2}{H^{4-\sigma}}\left(\alpha^2 H^2+\sigma(1-\sigma)(|A|^2-H^2/n)\right)+\sigma|A|^2f_\sigma\\
&=-\frac{|\nabla H|^2}{H^{2-\sigma}}\left(\alpha^2+\sigma(1-\sigma)(|A|^2/H^2-1/n)\right)+\sigma|A|^2f_\sigma
\end{align}

In the paper, this is simplified to
$$
-\alpha^2\frac{|\nabla H|^2}{H^{2-\sigma}}+\sigma|A|^2f_\sigma
$$
which makes sense since
$$
\sigma(1-\sigma)(|A|^2/H^2-1/n) \geq 0
$$
so it is a good term.

**Excerpt:** (The book uses $II$ for the second fundamental form $A$ and $\mathring{II}$ for the trace free second fundamental form $A-Hg/n$)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have the book, is it possible you add more detail, or use the notation in the original [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-20/issue-1/Flow-by-mean-curvature-of-convex-surfaces-into-spheres/10.4310/jdg/1214438998.full) by Huisken? (It seems that $f_\alpha$ in the paper is a bit different from your $f_{\sigma, \epsilon}$ though)

Comment: @ArcticChar I have edited the post to add an excerpt from the book, as well as Huisken's working. Huisken's argument makes sense to me. Let me know if I should elaborate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting an answer since I was able to resolve all the problems above. Firstly there is a mistake just above the "context" section where I have used the uniform convexity property incorrectly.

The main issue is that I had thought that $|A|^2\geq H^2$, however this is clearly incorrect if you write it out in terms of the principal curvatures
$$
|A|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\right)^2=H^2
$$
where $\lambda_i\geq 0$ for all $i$. Therefore the inequality $f_{\sigma,\epsilon}\leq H^\sigma$ is true.